# How can I add player parameters to a core oembed field for a youtube video?

Tags: 9, media

For example, if I enter this url that contains the player parameters to remove controls and autoplay, oembed field on my media type does not allow it ("The given URL does not match any known oEmbed providers.".

```
https://youtu.be/9ot0rIlhbNE?autoplay=1&fs=0&controls=0&modestbranding=1
```

[image: screenshot]

If I paste just the base url, then it works.

Any thoughts?

Edit: Based on Yuseferi answer, I have isolated the Youtube section if the providers.json.

```
{
    "provider_name": "YouTube",
    "provider_url": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/",
    "endpoints": [
        {
            "schemes": [
                "https:\/\/*.youtube.com\/watch*",
                "https:\/\/*.youtube.com\/v\/*",
                "https:\/\/youtu.be\/*"
            ],
            "url": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/oembed",
            "discovery": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: looks like validator fails, maybe try just youtube.com/token?autoplay=0 test with this module toohttps://www.drupal.org/project/soembed

Comment: Thanks for sharing that module. Unfortunately that module uses core oembed and therefore core oembed does the validation. That module is only usful for converting youtube urls via the text formats

Comment: is that just one field on you have a couple of this fields?
can you share your form_id and field machine name with me?

Comment: form id =media-type-edit-form     field machine name=field_media_oembed_video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem before with a local provider. So I share the solution I used and hope it works for you too.

The Drupal core, fetch providers form https://oembed.com/providers.json automatically. So you need to change the provider to what you want.

[Oembed Providers module](https://www.drupal.org/project/oembed_providers) helps to add custom providers too.

> - Add custom oEmbed providers via an admin user interface (providers are
>   stored in configuration)
> - Global enable/disable of providers
> - Modify the provider list URL (which is > defaulted to
>   https://oembed.com/providers.json)
> - Disable the fetching of the
>   provider list (useful in an instance where only custom providers are
>   used)
> - Provides hook_oembed_providers_alter() to alter provider
>   definitions

**So, all you need is to add a new provider for your custom provider "youtu.be"** with your parameters too.

try it and let me know if you need more details.;)

Screenshots that shows it's working without any validation error:

[image]

[image]

**what I did, was just add "oembed_providers" module and enabled it**

Comment: I added the info found in providers.json (in my original question above. Based on the schema, it should allow player parameters, no? or should I add the parameters to the schema Appended  like this? *?autoplay=*&fs=*&controls=*&modestbranding=*

Comment: @NigelWaters I think what you done based on my answer is correct. it that working for you now?

Comment: That is the default ones already in providers.json. It doesn;t make sense why it's not validation, as an * is appended. Theoretically it should be fine, but there seems to be a secondary validation somewhere

Comment: @NigelWaters "*" is the case here. 
if you want to exactly what you want it's better to add a custom validator to your form.

Comment: @NigelWaters do you still need more help or we're done?

Comment: My apoligies, I was on vacation. The challenge is not adding validators,; it's removing core from validating it. That module, is based on oembed core for the 2.x version. This means core, is doing the heavy lifting/validation and that module, just exposes a UI to core and ability to add new ones.

Comment: @NigelWaters as you can see in the question screenshot, it return an error on the custom URL that you provided as data. These custom providers help you.
but if you want to have a validator that validates the pattern you exactly want maybe it could be another question that I can help you too.

Comment: I don't need a validator. I need to bypass core's oembed validator

Comment: @NigelWaters then it must work for you. I tried it and on my project, it's worked with your given URL. sorry, but I confused what is the problem now?

Comment: do you think you share a screenshot of your attempt?

Comment: I awarded the bounty as it was about to expire. Thank you for your great work so far, however I am still not there yet. When I add the URLs as mentioned above in the "Endpoint schemes", it says https://youtu.be/* is not valid. If you managed to get this working, would you mind sharing a screenshot of your custom oEmbed provider settings where it works? It would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: @NigelWaters sorry I was away from the system. I revert the changes after I saw it's working. I'll plan to it one more time for you and I'll screenshot of the result.
do you mind if I'll do it tonight?

Comment: No problem at all. I just really appreciate the help. This one has me stumped.

Comment: @NigelWaters question updated with two screenshots

Comment: thanks for doing that. I was hoping you could post a screenshot of your custom provider settings? I can't get it to accept mine

Comment: thanks for screenshots but I was hoping for a shot of your custom parameter settings as mine don't seem to be working as formatted. This is the last piece of my project and I appreciate the help so far.

Comment: Does doing it this way actually respect the parameters? My validation is all working but when I use a URL like this it doesn't actually respect these "?autoplay=1&mute=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&loop=1&modestbranding=1&wmode=transparent"

Comment: Hi, I also have the contrib module working but the parameters are not respected. I need to disable the shortcuts on the video player by add disablekb=1 to youtube video's and keyboard=false to vimeo video's I tried adding these in the url:
https://vimeo.com/672844590?keyboard=false but this doesn't work. Did anyone solve this issue?